# How can I add a callback to a function with multiple async calls in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, asynccallback

```
function jsoncall(){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/data", function (data) {...});
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/data", function (data) {...});
}

jsoncall.callback(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

Something like the pseudocode above. Is there a method in JavaScript that considers async calls like the `getJSON` above?

Comment: Isn't the `function (data) {...}` the callback? :)

Comment: Functionally, `jsoncall` is just like `$.getJSON` - you could simply do `jsoncall = $.getJSON` since they are functionally equal. If you need to **wait** until it's done, then I would recommend looking into `$.Deferred` or ES6 Promises.

Comment: `function jsoncall(){ return $.getJSON(...) }` and then `jsoncall().then(callback)` But the deferred-implementation of jQuery is imo. something between not good and awful, depending on the version you're using. I'd reccomend you taking a look at "real" promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Deferred : [https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/][1]

```
function jsoncall(){
     var $def = $.Deferred();
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/data", function (data) {

      $def.resolve(data);

    });

    return $def;
}
jsoncall.done(function(data){
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: Wasn't looking for a callback for the getJSON, deferred part was what  I wanted, setting as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking what I think you are, then you need to implement the `callback` *in* the function.

```
function jsonCall(callback) {
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/data', function(data) {
        ....
        callback(data);
    });
}

jsonCall(function(data) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Wasn't looking for a callback for the getJSON but rather the entire function as a whole because it would have multiple getJSONs, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

[Async Call Explained(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48594476/7579856)

Make a utils.js and put your ajax function there call it where ever required.

```
//utils.js    
function doAjax(callbackFunc, method, url) {
      var xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlHttpReq.open(method, url);
      xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {

          if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpReq.status == 200) {
            callbackFunc(xmlHttpReq.responseText,buttonArrayInit);
          }


      }
      xmlHttpReq.send(null);

    }



    function loadMyJson(categoryValue){
      if(categoryValue==="veg")
      doAjax(print,"GET","http://localhost:3004/vegetables");
      else if(categoryValue==="fruits")
      doAjax(print,"GET","http://localhost:3004/fruits");
      else 
      console.log("Data not found");
    }
```